# Opening a file location directly with file explorer

Tags: android, file, android-intent, explorer

How can I open a file/folder using default file explorer? For example: I have a folder whose path is`/root/user/sd/mystuff`, I want to open this path directly with the default file explorer. I have searched but didn't find any answer providing solution for this. So if I use `setData&type` instead of `setType`, will it open the provided path directly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
....
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:/root/user/sd/mystuff), "file/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

you can do this to accomplish your task the code is given below..

```
public void openFolder()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/myFolder/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, " ");//specify your type
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the MIME type be `file/*` ? What this text/csv type represents?

Comment: which type of u want to open

Comment: well the provided path can direct to any one file or folder? if it is a file, so it can have any format/extension thats why I am opening it with the default explorer and not creating one myself.

Comment: you can use  intent.setType("file/*");

Comment: thats why I asked you what text/csv type is for?

Comment: text/csv is used for report files

Comment: Can you link me to the site which provides the info about all the MIME types?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35489/discussion-between-prakhar-and-umer-farooq)

Comment: This is not working. File Explorer is not opening the folder provided in the path, besides it is opening the root directory always.